# .NET6, Getting away from appsettings.json for App Service (Web App) by leveraging the Azure Functions local.settings.json strategy

Tags: azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0, appsettings

I'd like to store all of my Application setting within Azure Configuration, but cannot seem to escape the need to maintain an **AppSettings.json** file.

**AppSettings.json** files are deployed to my Azure environment and are referenced in **Release**.

I'd like to adapt the Azure Function strategy of using a **local.settings.json**

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

To use Azure App Configuration in an Azure Web App without relying on `appsettings.json`,

1. **Integrate Azure App Configuration in Your ASP.NET Core Web App**:

   - Add the required packages to your project:

     ```bash
     dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration
     ```
   - Modify your `Program.cs` to use Azure App Configuration during the host build process:

     ```cs
     public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
         Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
             .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
             {
                 webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                 {
                     var settings = config.Build();
                     var connection = settings["ConnectionStrings:AppConfig"]; // This will still need an initial setup.
                     config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(connection);
                 })
                 .UseStartup<Startup>();
             });
     ```
2. **Initial Configuration Source**: The catch here is that you will need some way to tell your application where Azure App Configuration is located, essentially a pointer. This typically is a connection string. While you want to move away from `appsettings.json`, you still need some minimal bootstrapping configuration. You can set this in the environment settings of your Azure Web App. Under the `Settings` section of your Web App in the Azure portal, go to `Configuration` and add the connection string for Azure App Configuration.
3. **Development Environment**: For local development, you might want to set the connection string as an environment variable on your local machine, or use a secrets management tool like the `dotnet user-secrets` command for .NET Core. This keeps your development environment smooth without relying on `appsettings.json`.
4. **Deployment**: When deploying to Azure Web Apps, your app will retrieve the Azure App Configuration connection string from the environment setting (as set in step 3) and then fetch all configuration from Azure App Configuration.

You can also setup a service connection between Web App and App Configuration using System Managed Identity or User Managed Identity.
Following GitHub Repo has Samples for different approaches.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/serviceconnector-webapp-appconfig-dotnet

There is a tutorial also available:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-connector/tutorial-connect-web-app-app-configuration?tabs=serviceprincipal